# AWS EC2 - Installing self signed certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to install a SSL certificate on my EC2 instance. I used [this post](http://akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) as a guide.

I receive an error when I perform step 5 by running the following command:

```
cp server.crt /usr/local/apache/conf/ssl.crt
```

I get an error saying `no such dir or file`.

How can I best resolve this?

Comment: Does `server.crt` exist in your current directory?

Comment: what's your current location when you're calling cp? I would provide the full directory information just as you did for the destination file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu, Apache is not installed in `/usr/local/apache` (by default)

Instead, copy `server.crt` to `/etc/ssl/certs` and copy `server.key` to `/etc/ssl/private`

You then need to configure Apache by editing `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl` and setting:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
```